# Spring Security manually setting authentication without authentication manager giving error

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I am setting authentication manually in my application using PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken. But I keep getting error as follows,

No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined: Did you forget to add a gobal  element to your configuration (with child  elements)?

I don't have a UserDetailsService as it is not required for me. Please help me on how to configure authentication manager ?

Comment: Post your relevant security configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `<authentication-manager>` element. You need to have one which processes the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`, usually adding any relevant roles for the user. If you want it to be a no-op operation, then that's fine, but it still has to be there, so you can either implement a simple `UserDetailsService` which just returns a user object with a fixed role, or you can implement `AuthenticationProvider` directly and create the final token in its `authenticate` method, however you want to do it. Either way, the configuration would be similar to [the one described in the user manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#preauth).